# clip command error in batch

Tags: command-line, batch

I have a script file that prints something, then with this command:

```
.\path.py |clip
```

I send the output directly to my computer clipboard, so if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> I can instantly paste it.

It works perfectly on my main computer but on the other one it gives an error related to a pipeline, I'm sorry but it's not in the English language and I can't find the English version in the internet.

It's like 'unable to open document in pipeline'.

Comment: What output does `path.py` give when run directly from the console? Are both computers on Windows and which version? Do they both have installed the same python version?

Comment: Assuming just `.\path.py` works on another computer, I suggest you try **`2>&1 (.\path.py) | clip`** or **`(2>&1 .\path.py) | clip`**

Comment: that script is simply a Python version verifier:
import sys - locate_python = sys.exec_prefix - print(locate_python + "\\")
(assuming the "-" symbol as new line, here in comments the <br /> does not work so I put the "-" to separate lines, it's a three line script, super easy

Comment: the two computers are both on Windows 11 and the Python version is the same